# How to override create methode in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, odoo-10

i want to use same create method in `odoo 10` as below means i want to convert below code in odoo 10, `below code` is working well for `odoo 8`

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    phase_obj = self.pool.get('hr_evaluation.plan.phase')
    survey_id = phase_obj.read(cr, uid, vals.get('phase_id'), fields=['survey_id'], context=context)['survey_id'][0]

    if vals.get('user_id'):
        user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
        partner_id = user_obj.read(cr, uid, vals.get('user_id'), fields=['partner_id'], context=context)['partner_id'][0]
    else:
        partner_id = None

    user_input_obj = self.pool.get('survey.user_input')

    if not vals.get('deadline'):
        vals['deadline'] = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=28)).strftime(DF)

    ret = user_input_obj.create(cr, uid, {'survey_id': survey_id,
                                          'deadline': vals.get('deadline'),
                                          'type': 'link',
                                          'partner_id': partner_id}, context=context)
    vals['request_id'] = ret
    return super(hr_evaluation_interview, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
```

i am trying below code:

```
def create(self, vals):
    survey_id = self.env['hr_evaluation.plan.phase'].read(vals.get('phase_id'),fields=['survey_id'])['survey_id'][0]

    if vals.get('user_id'):
        partner_id = self.env['res.users'].read(vals.get('user_id'), fields=['partner_id'])['partner_id'][0]
    else:
        partner_id = None

    if not vals.get('deadline'):
        vals['deadline'] = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=28)).strftime(DF)

    ret = self.env['survey.user_input'].create({'survey_id': survey_id,
                                          'deadline': vals.get('deadline'),
                                          'type': 'link',
                                          'partner_id': partner_id})
    vals['request_id'] = ret
    return super(hr_evaluation_interview, self).create(vals)
```

but it is giving me error like `TypeError: read() got multiple values for keyword argument 'fields'` so please guide me how can i remove this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` method accept `fields` as argument and you give it two arguments.

```
read([fields])
```

Reads the requested fields for the records in self, low-level/RPC method. In Python code, prefer browse().

```
Parameters
    fields -- list of field names to return (default is all fields)
Returns
    a list of dictionaries mapping field names to their values, with one dictionary per record
Raises
    AccessError -- if user has no read rights on some of the given records
```

Instead of calling `read` method it's better to call `browse()` method, you can read [Browse() vs read() performance in Odoo 8](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/odoo-argentina/5ExoOKlGmdI)

Your code should be:

```
def create(self, vals):
    survey_id = self.env['hr_evaluation.plan.phase'].browse(vals.get('phase_id'))

    if vals.get('user_id'):
        partner_id = self.env['res.users'].browse(vals.get('user_id'))
    else:
        partner_id = None

    if not vals.get('deadline'):
        vals['deadline'] = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=28)).strftime(DF)

    ret = self.env['survey.user_input'].create({'survey_id': survey_id.id,
                                          'deadline': vals.get('deadline'),
                                          'type': 'link',
                                          'partner_id': partner_id.id})
    vals['request_id'] = ret.id
    return super(hr_evaluation_interview, self).create(vals)
```

Comment: sir your code giving me this error `
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'survey.user_input'` can you please tell me something about it?

Comment: i think problem is in last tow lines please sir tell me something about it

Comment: Sorry to reply late. I think the problem is in `ret` try to pass `ret.id` instead.

Comment: Thanks sir.. i found it